# Can anyone find the mistake in the hibernate query?

Tags: hibernate

I have the following query in ***hibernate*** :

```
 session.createQuery("FROM RegionFile T1 WHERE (T1.action = 'MODIFY' or T1.action = 'CREATE' or (T1.action = 'NONE' " +
                        "AND T1.docid NOT IN (SELECT T2.docid FROM RegionFile T2 WHERE T2.action in ( 'MODIFY','DELETE')))) " +
                       "AND T1.rgndoc like '%" + dgId + "%'")
```

But, i get the following error :

> query syntax exception

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

```
I tried in MySql database and it successfully execute have used below query...please try again and check carefully spaces. 

Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Region T1 WHERE (T1.action = 'MOD' or T1.action = 'CRT' or (T1.action = 'NON' " +
                            "AND T1.id NOT IN (SELECT T2.id FROM Region T2 WHERE T2.action in ( 'MOD','DEL')))) " +
                           "AND T1.rgndoc like '%" + dgId + "%'");          
            List<Region> list = query.list();
            Iterator<Region> itr = list.iterator();
            System.out.println("before calling");
            while(itr.hasNext())
              System.out.println(itr.next().getAction());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest by following for your problem.

createQuery("FROM RegionFile T1 WHERE (T1.action = 'MODIFY' or T1.action ='CREATE' or (T1.action = 'NONE' " +"AND T1.docid NOT IN (SELECT T2.docid FROM RegionFile T2 WHERE T2.action in ( 'MODIFY','DELETE'))) " +"AND T1.rgndoc like '%" + a + "%')")